# C++ switch statement. Default not working

Tags: c++

I've been searching and trying different things for an hour and can't figure this out. Why doesn't my default work? If I enter 1-4, the output is as expected. However, if I enter any other number or letter, nothing is displayed. I would like the default to display if I enter any other number or letter.

RESOLVED: It was my compiler. Going to use Visual Studio only from now on. (VS didn't show my default at first because I was using it incorrectly.) Thanks to everyone for your responses.

My code:

```
int main()
{
  int num;

cout << "Please enter the code stamped on the storage drive (1-4): ";
cin  >> num;

switch (num)
{
       case 1:
            cout << "The code you entered was 1; therefore, the storage capacity is 2GB." << endl;
            break;
       case 2:
            cout << "The code you entered was 2; therefore, the storage capacity is 4GB." << endl;
            break;
       case 3:
            cout << "The code you entered was 3; therefore, the storage capacity is 16GB." << endl;
            break;
       case 4:
            cout << "The code you entered was 4; therefore, the storage capacity is 32GB." << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid selection - Please input 1 to 4 only.";
            break;

}           //end of switch


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you ignore the return value of your I/O operation.

Comment: What did you enter when it didn't work?

Comment: Try putting  `<< endl` at the end of the output line for the default case to flush the output before the program ends.

Comment: define "not working" Is one of the other blocks executing instead? or just... nothing?

Comment: Compiled and ran this code and the default is working for me.  That being said entering a string value could cause undefined behavior as the switch statement expects integers or values that decay into integers.

Comment: If I enter numbers 1-4, I get the expected output. If I enter any other number or letter, it does not display the default sentence.

Comment: I tried << endl at one time. It doesn't change my output.

Comment: Fred Thomsen, what compiler did you run it in? I've tried Visual Studio 2010 and Dev-C++ 5.6.0.

Comment: @user3314420 If you enter a valid number outside the range of your switch tags, it *does* hit  the default case: [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/aHMFOp). But an invalid (non-numeric) entry leaving `num` indeterminate *might* not, depending on the cruft currently occupying `num`.

Comment: I've tried this on xcode and the default does not execute on it. I will try a different compiler.

Answer (score 4):

The `default` *is* working (I've tested it), subject to the following caveats.

First of all, the way your code is structured, you have to enter *something*. If you just press Enter, nothing will happens because `cin >> num` will continue waiting for a number.

Secondly, when you enter anything that's not a number, `cin  >> num` fails and leaves `num` uninitialized. This leads to [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in the `switch`.

You should initialize `num` (say to `0` or another invalid value) and/or check whether `cin >> num` has succeeded:

```
if (cin >> num) {
  // the read has succeeded
} else {
  // the read has failed
}
```

Comment: The question says - "why is the default not working?"

Comment: Yeah this doesnt really answer the question

Comment: +1 If `num` is fortunate (or not) enough to hold one of the switch tags during its lifetime of indeterminate state, this explains *exactly* why `default` is never hit. Knowing the OP's observation of "not working" would be helpful, but doesn't change the correctness of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding either a `'\n'` to the end of your default message or a `<< endl`.

Looks like the text from the `default` is waiting to be flushed.

You could also add a `cout.flush();` before the end of your program.

Answer (score -4):

I know this is pointless saying anything as this was a while ago, but for those who have a similar problem look at your code.... case 1: it should instead case '1': the same applies for every other case, then your switch statement will work